vue js vs code launch.json sourceMapPathOverrides not correct - breakpoints not hit
(Apologies in advance for the potentially easy/silly question, but I've done tons of research and I haven't figured this out... though I think I'm close and it's a simple fix)
When I add breakpoints to my vue files in VSCode they are unbound.
If I use the Debug Diagnostics it shows me the attached image.

I'm pretty sure I need to adjust my sourceMapPathOverrides, but the values I'm adding aren't working.
This is what my launch.json file looks like at the moment:
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "vuejs: chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:5000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/axios/adriantma/src/*",
      "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/axios/adriantma/src/*",
      "/./*": "${webRoot}/axios/adriantma/src/*",
      "/src/*": "${webRoot}/axios/adriantma/src/*",
      "/*": "${webRoot}/axios/adriantma/*",
    }
  }
]
}

Here is the sources tab in Developer Tools in Chrome. I can add breakpoints to these files and they are hit, so I think it's just a mapping problem and this should be fixed.
I have no idea why there are so many duplicates of each file, but the others are minified or something and hard/impossible to read. The one file I highlighted in red is what looks like my code in the editor

I think I just need to map the axios/adriantma/src folder from the Sources tab in chrome correctly in my sourceMapPathOverrides and it will work, but no combination I've tried yet works.
